# Moving OpenCl code from AMD machine to Nvidia machine

Tags: opencl, gpu, nvidia, amd-processor

I have a basic prime generating code of openCL which currently works on AMD machine I want to port the same code to nvidia machine, I wasn't able to do it, I looked at the samples provided during the installation of openCl for nvidia, The code format is a lot different. I would like to know to make the prime code on nvidia.

Comment: What specifically isn't working?  Do your kernels fail to compile?  What are the errors?  OpenCL should abstract platforms as much as possible and let your code work as-is on different devices.

Comment: I don't understand the question here. It is not even straightforward. It should be trivial, just copy->paste the .exe and run. Directly. Since OpenCL is supported in both platforms. What do you need to convert?

Answer (score 0):

[SWAN](http://www.multiscalelab.org/swan) project may be worth looking into to convert between CUDA and OpenCL (the opposite of what you want). Thanks [Tom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2088135/tom-fenech) for pointing out my mistake.

From that page,

> Possible uses include:
>
> - Evaluating OpenCL performance of an existing CUDA code.
> - Maintaining a dual-target OpenCL and CUDA code.
> - Reducing dependence on NVCC when compiling host code.
> - Support multiple CUDA compute capabilities in a single binary
> - A runtime library for managing OpenCL kernels for new development

From my (limited) knowledge there is no tool that does the opposite (what you ask).

Comment: The Swan project works the other way round (CUDA -> OpenCL), although the OpenCL code should be transferable between AMD and NVIDIA platforms anyway.